# Maven Could not transfer artifact from/to repo1.maven.org

Tags: java, maven, flume-ng

I am trying to build Apache Flume using `mvn install -DskipTests` on SLES12.

Error Message goes:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flume.flume-ng-sinks:flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink:jar:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:0.90.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:0.90.1: Could not transfer artifact org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:pom:0.90.1 from/to repo1.maven.org (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): init failed: /dev/[u]random closed? -> [Help 1]

I noticed that the `settings.xml` is missing in `.m2` folder. I could think about 2 possible reasons:

1. lastUpdated file in `.m2` prevent Maven to progress
2. it is behind the proxy.

How to verify which goes wrong and fix it?

Comment: Well, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi Tunaki, I think the server directly connects to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. I didn't change any network setting.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after I changed the open JDK version.